# Parse Users not saving in Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I added a new column to my user information so I decided to delete all the current users so that I could recreate them with the new information.  Now even though it is telling me in the code that the user has been saved in the background it is nowhere to be found in the User class in Parse.com 
This is my code

```
    let userName = userNameTextField.text;
    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userGender = userGenderTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;
    let userRepeatPassword = userRepeatPasswordTextField.text;
    let userPhoneNumber = PhoneNumberTextField.text;
 // Store data

    let SpotterAccount:PFUser = PFUser();

    SpotterAccount.username = userName
    SpotterAccount.email = userEmail
    SpotterAccount.password = userPassword
    SpotterAccount[ "gender" ] = userGender
    SpotterAccount["phonenumber"] = userPhoneNumber

    SpotterAccount.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        println("Spotter Account succesfully created")



    // Display alert message with confirmation
    var Alert = UIAlertController(title: "Congradulations!", message: "Your Spotter Account has been created", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
        action in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
    }

    Alert.addAction(okAction);
    self.presentViewController(Alert, animated:true, completion:nil);

    }

}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? It was working fine 15 minutes ago.  I do not know what has happened. Please help 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the spacing with "gender" might be generating the error.

Comment: Ok so I figured out my issue.  I set the new column as a Number not a String.  Thanks